# HDP 3.1.5 | Hive Create Role issue

Tags: hive, hdp, apache-ranger

I have installed HDP 3.1.5 with KERBEROS security. installed Ranger Plugin .after setting up the hive authentication as Ranger . Getting below error .
Please suggest the resolution

create role userRole; Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: LockException [Error 10280]: Error communicating with the metastore (state=42000,code=10280) Changed the value : hive.security.authorization.manager = org.apache.ranger.authorization.hive.authorizer.RangerHiveAuthorizerFactory

Error in Hive log :

2020-03-30T10:38:08,555 ERROR [json-metric-reporter]: metrics2.JsonFileMetricsReporter (:()) - Unable to rename temp file /tmp/hmetrics4237869098581745036json to /tmp/report.json
2020-03-30T10:38:08,555 ERROR [json-metric-reporter]: metrics2.JsonFileMetricsReporter (:()) - Exception during rename
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /tmp/hmetrics4237869098581745036json -> /tmp/report.json: Operation not permitted
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:396) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.metrics.metrics2.JsonFileMetricsReporter.run(JsonFileMetricsReporter.java:175) ~[hive-common-3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152.jar:3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152]